# Split Mysql Column Data in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Table Splidata
and column names is ID,Product,Cost,Remarks

The Product Column Contains the Following String.

`BROCHURE ( SIZE:11x17 FOLDING:Double Gate Fold PAPER:100lb Gloss Book with Aqueous Coating (C2S) COLOR:full/full TURNAROUND:Standard )`

Now i want to Display the data when fetch from the mysql database in the below format.
(For the Product Column). Rest of the columns data is too there.

```
+------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| Size       | Folding          | Paper                                      | COLOR                          |
+------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|      11x17 | Double Gate Fold | 100lb Gloss Book with Aqueous Coating (C2S)| full/full TURNAROUND:Standard  |
+------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: Did hit hit "Submit" too early?

Comment: i don't really understand what is the question

Comment: If you hit "Submit" by mistake, please note that you can edit the question (and/or remove it until you're done).

Comment: Please Checks again i will update the Description. Yes the Submit button hits accidently first.

Answer (score 0):

you can use mysql SUBSTRING_INDEX

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php

for example if you want to extract size use

```
  select 
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(product, 'SIZE:', -1) , ' ' ,1) AS size
  ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(product, 'FOLDING:', -1) , 'PAPER:' ,1) AS  Folding  
  ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(product, 'PAPER:', -1) , 'COLOR:' ,1) AS  PAPER  
  ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(product, 'COLOR:', -1) , ' )' ,1) AS  COLOR  
  from Splidata
```